# creating view with xib from viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiview

I want to create a View that has a xib.

But instead of creating the xib file separately, I want to start with ViewController, and then convert it to UIView.

(can't create view controller with xib on xcode:
[image]

)

What do I need to do, except making the class inherit from UIView instead of UIViewController?

- Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create ViewController file, then create View (xib) by IB, and finally wire these things as below image:

[image: ss]